# Are WebGL draw calls really, really slow?

Tags: optimization, webgl

I haven't used desktop OpenGL in a while, but WebGL seems really slow.
With just a couple hundreds of relatively simple draw calls, FPS goes down the dump.

My code is pretty much as optimized as it gets, I think.
It renders models, where each model is composed of batches that are mesh+material, and each batch is rendered with instanced rendering so as to render all instances of the model, each instance with its own per-instance data like transformation, etc.

Is there something I am missing?

As a side note, normal renders are slower, as expected, from instanced renders, yet a couple of hundred calls still destroy the frame rate.

Comment: WebGL draw calls have significantly more overhead than their desktop OpenGL counterparts, but you should be able to do a couple of thousand at 60fps (given trivial circumstances). As it stands, your question is pretty generic. You should probably isolate specific testcases and ask for help on those if performance analysis doesn't get you any further.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is using hw acceleration ?

Comment: The question is pretty generic because there isn't anything specific. My shaders are very simple (basically pass-through with world-to-NDC transformations on the vertex shader), the models have maybe a few hundred triangles in static buffers, there's hardly any GL setup for the draw calls...I really can't understand how it's so slow.

Comment: too generic question. please provide example code :-)

Comment: @user2503048 Could you mark this as answered, or answer it yourself by posting your findings? Thanks.

Comment: There are no findings. The last time I checked, it was very inconsistent, with the same demo running easily at 60FPS for some bad old integrated GPU, and clawing the 20FPS mark for a high end GPU card. Who knows...

Answer (score 8):

Slow compared to what? Unity and Unreal both export to WebGL and are getting reasonable speed. I get 6000+ draw calls at 60fps [on this demo](http://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html) on my early 2015 MBP in Chrome running in integrated graphics mode (ATM too lazy to switch to discrete which would be faster). I set it to 4000 fish, then pasted this in the JavaScript console `g_fishTable[0].num[8] = 6000`.  Even taking it to 16000 draw calls I'm still getting 43fps.

Is it possible you're generating garbage? As an example

```
 gl.uniform4fv(someLocation, [1, 2, 3, 4]);  // Generates garbage
```

That line creates potentially creates a new array every time.

Similarly are you making new matrices every frame or re-using old ones to make sure you're not generating garbage.

Also type arrays should be faster than standard JavaScript arrays

In other words

```
var vector = [0, 0, 0, 0];   // slow
```

vs

```
var vector = new Float32Array(4);  // fast
```

It may or may not be faster to create them but that shouldn't matter since you should be creating them at init time not render time. Usage though typedarrays will be faster in pretty much every case AFAIK.

Maybe you should check the [JavaScript profiler](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling).

Comment: I get almost the same performance on GTX 860M laptop GPU: solid 60fps @ 6200 fish.

Comment: Well this is odd. I am getting to 40FPs on Chrome with 250 fish, with an HD 7950. About my code - no, there is no garbage being generated (heap allocations smaller than 100 bytes, probably for local variables?), everything uses typed arrays, and so on. I just tested rendering a pyramid (as a sphere with 3 stacks/slices), and at 3000 draws, with no other code executing, it goes down to 40FPS. I am, however, seeing something weird in the profiler, which I haven't checked in a while - instead of saying I am calling WebGLRenderingContext.drawElements, or whatever, it belongs to some "glp" object.

Comment: Oops, I had WebGL Insight turned on, that's the glp thing. Other than that, performance is about the same also with Insight being off. The only difference is that the CPU side (aka profiler) now has hardly any usage whatsoever, at about 5-7%, but the FPS is still at 40-45 or so.

Comment: @user2503048  "*I am getting to 40FPs on Chrome with 250 fish, with an HD 7950*" are you sure you're GPU accelerated, check `about://gpu` i'm having a solid 30fps with 4000 fish on an Intel HD 4000 ...

Comment: Updated my drivers. Now 1000 fish are solid 60fps, but it drops down to 35fps for 2000 fish. How is it possible my GPU is slower than an integrated one? Yes, WebGL is hardware accelerated. I don't get this.

Comment: Had someone test the aquarium demo on his phone, and he is getting better results than my HD 7950...and then I checked what the GPU is actually doing with GPUZ, and it's at 1-19% load with 4000 fish, with the demo running at 18fps. What on earth is going on here?